# Passing int to sysfs

Tags: c, char, kernel, driver, sysfs

I want to pass int to sysfs_store

What I tried

userspace

```
int tid = 5234; // can be negative as well
char buf[5];
sprintf(buf, "%d\n", tid);
write (fd, buf, 1);
```

driver sysfs_store

```
int v;
kstrtoint(buf,10,&v);
pr_info("%d\n",v); // printing only first digit 5. Should print 5234
```

Comment: Remember that C strings are *null-terminated*. To fit four digits, the newline *and* the null-terminator, you need an array of *six* characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sprintf()` returns bytes copied count; use it

Also switch to `snprintf()` to avoid buffer overflows.

```
int data_len = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d\n", tid);
write (fd, buf, data_len);
```

It's always better to have bigger buffers to cover all your scenarios.